# Failed to import Numeric: No module named Numeric in F2PY

Tags: python, ubuntu, numpy, numeric, f2py

When I am trying to use F2PY, I'll get the error:

```
Failed to import Numeric: No module named Numeric
```

I know that numeric is dead and instead we should use numpy. But files:

`/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/f2py2e/src/fortranobject.h` and 
`/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/f2py2e/f2py2e.py` both use the Numeric package. I tried to replace it with numpy, but I was not successful.

I used to use f2py without any problem, but after I formatted my computer and got a fresh copy of Ubuntu, I have this problem.

I also tried to use the option `--2d-numpy` for f2py like:

`f2py -c --fcompiler=intel --2d-numpy -m processoutput processoutput.f`

But it didn't work, and it is still looking for numpy.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You may be using an outdated version. I believe the most recent releases of F2PY use NumPy.

Comment: I don't think so, how can I check or where can I get the latest version, I got myself from http://cens.ioc.ee/projects/f2py2e/#installation which said it is the latest version.

Comment: Look higher. "F2PY is now part of [NumPy](http://numpy.scipy.org/). All the development and maintenance of F2PY is carried out under NumPy SVN tree. See [F2PY](http://www.scipy.org/F2py) for more information. If you need F2PY with Numeric or Numarray array support then you must use the F2PY version found below."

Comment: Okay, I tried to import the numpy in python and it worked so I assumed I have the numpy. I only downloaded and installed f2py from the mentioned source in the above which gave me the error with numeric. I used the numeric from below. Then it gave me error about distutils, so I downloaded numpy and installed it and now f2py is working fine.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can download old versions of Numeric here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/numpy/files/Old%20Numeric/24.2/

If you install that, I think f2py will be satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar situation using msys under Windows, and indeed I was trying to use an outdated version of f2py.  The newer version is included with numpy (and doesn't need to be installed separately).  And can be found in the site-packages/numpy/f2py directory.  Although my setup is a bit different, I was able to compile from python using this script:

```
import numpy.f2py.f2py2e as f2py2e
import sys

sys.argv +=  "-c -m hello hello.f".split()
f2py2e.main()
```